# Why is my annotation_text in python plotly.figure_factory getting the wrong coordinates in some cells?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, plotly, plotly-python, complexheatmap

I'm getting some behavior I don't understand.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z=np.array([[30.0, 15.0, 14.72899729, 7.72994652, 19.61096606, 15.49867374, 19.85271318, 30.0],
         [30.0, 15.0, 22.36842105, 4.80104712, 20.99742268, 21.51211073, 23.5408971, 0.0],
         [30.0, 15.0, 7.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.63095238, 30.0]])
y = ['Ref:14973', 'Ref:17746', 'Ref:21846']
x = ['MN908947.3', '2361', '2371', '2373', '2374', '2375', '2376', 'Warnings']
z_text = np.array([['G','A', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'A', 'A', ','],
                 ['C', 'C', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'C', ',hp'],
                 ['C', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', ',']])
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
    z, x=x,y=y,
    annotation_text=z_text,
    colorscale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn,
    font_colors=['black'],
    showscale=True,
    customdata= dft44,
    hovertemplate= "Sample: %{x} <br>Position: %{y} <br>Score: %{z} <br>BAM: %{customdata}")
fig.update_yaxes(
        title_text = "Pos",
        title_standoff = 25)
fig.show()
```

If you zoom in a lot you see that it is almost working, the text from z_text is in the right spot in the first and the last columns (MN908947.3 and warnings) but not the middle columns (2361 through 2376)

[image: Zoomed in]

If you reset axis you can see the missing z_text labels bunched in the far right:

[image: ![Zoomed out]

I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug with `plotly.figure_factory` where the chart renderer is probably having some trouble with `x = ['MN908947.3', '2361', '2371', '2373', '2374', '2375', '2376', 'Warnings']` because the annotations stop being correctly placed once the x array changes from `'MN908947.3' to '2361'` meaning that there is some confusion between strings and numbers.

My original workaround was to place some non-numeric symbol before the numbers, such as an equals sign (`'='`), so that they are interpreted as strings, but a better workaround is to pass the argument `x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` to `ff.create_annotated_heatmap` and then later update the xaxes so that the ticktext at these xticks are the xvalues that you actually want to display.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z=np.array([[30.0, 15.0, 14.72899729, 7.72994652, 19.61096606, 15.49867374, 19.85271318, 30.0],
         [30.0, 15.0, 22.36842105, 4.80104712, 20.99742268, 21.51211073, 23.5408971, 0.0],
         [30.0, 15.0, 7.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.63095238, 30.0]])
y = ['Ref:14973', 'Ref:17746', 'Ref:21846']

x = ['MN908947.3', '2361', '2371', '2373', '2374', '2375', '2376', 'Warnings']
z_text = np.array([['G','A', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'A', 'A', ','],
                 ['C', 'C', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'C', ',hp'],
                 ['C', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', ',']])
fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
    z, x=list(range(len(x))),y=y,
    annotation_text=z_text,
    colorscale=px.colors.diverging.RdYlGn,
    font_colors=['black'],
    # showscale=True,
    # customdata= dft44,
    hovertemplate= "Sample: %{x} <br>Position: %{y} <br>Score: %{z} <br>BAM: %{customdata}")
fig.update_yaxes(
    title_text = "Pos",
    title_standoff = 25,
)
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=list(range(len(x))), ticktext=x)
fig.show()
```

[image]